# Manipulating a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file in the following format:

```
Surname, Forename: Day.Month.Year: Degree

Sellen, Jo: 03.07.1986: MSc CSE

Parfitt, Harry: 20.03.1984: MSc IT
```

How can I write a shell script that uses awk to read the file (`class.txt`) like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/ +/,"\t");print}' class.txt
```

and outputs the data in the following format, that exchanges the second and third column:

```
Surname Forename MSc stream Date of Birth

Sellen Jo MSc CSE 03.07.1986 

Parfitt Harry MSc IT 20.03.1984
```

<sub>(Don't worry if tabbed columns don't line up)</sub>

Comment: This site is not for getting other people to do your CS homework for you. Please spend some time working through some [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) [tutorials](http://www.google.com.tr/search?q=awk+tutorial) on the web and then come back here if you have specific usage questions.

Comment: @Caleb I left this open because we've generally allowed "script this for me questions" (at least small ones like this), but you can [bring it up on meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=on-topic) if you think we should get rid of them

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the explanation. I might just [do that](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/578/1925).

Comment: @Caleb: On the other sites you get "clues" to the solution if you tag the question with "homework", why not the same here?

Answer (score 3):

It appears your fields are separated with colon-space, so you'll need to account for that in awk's `FS` variable.  You're also manipulating the order of the fields, so you'll want to set `OFS` in the `BEGIN` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[,:]" } { print $1, $2, $4, $5, $3 }' input_file
```

Here, we specify multiple field separators (, and :) using the AWK built in variable, `FS`. Multiple field separators are enclosed within `[]`.